# Using Regular Expressions in JSP EL

Tags: regex, jsp, el

In EL expressions, used in a jsp page, strings are taken literally.  For example, in the following code snippet

```
<c:when test="${myvar == 'prefix.*'}">
```

test does not evaluate to true if the value of myvar is 'prefixxxxx.'   Does anyone know if there is a way to have the string interpreted as a regex instead?  Does EL have something similar to awk's tilde ~ operator?

Answer (score 19):

While this special case can be handled with the JSTL `fn:startsWith` function, regular expressions in general seem like very likely tests. It's unfortunate that JSTL doesn't include a function for these.

On the bright side, it's pretty easy to write an EL function that does what you want. You need the function implementation, and a TLD to let your web application know where to find it. Put these together in a JAR and drop it into your WEB-INF/lib directory.

Here's an outline:

com/x/taglib/core/Regexp.java:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Regexp {

  public static boolean matches(String pattern, CharSequence str) {
    return Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(str).matches();
  }

}
```

META-INF/x-c.tld:

```
<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
  <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
  <short-name>x-c</short-name>
  <uri>http://dev.x.com/taglib/core/1.0</uri>
  <function>
    <description>Test whether a string matches a regular expression.</description>
    <display-name>Matches</display-name>
    <name>matches</name>
    <function-class>com.x.taglib.core.Regexp</function-class>
    <function-signature>boolean matches(java.lang.String, java.lang.CharSequence)</function-signature>
  </function>
</taglib>
```

Sorry, I didn't test this particular function, but I hope it's enough to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 6):

Simply add the following to WEB-INF/tags.tld

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<taglib version="2.1"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd">

    <display-name>Acme tags</display-name>
    <short-name>custom</short-name>
    <uri>http://www.acme.com.au</uri>
    <function>
        <name>matches</name>
        <function-class>java.util.regex.Pattern</function-class>
        <function-signature>
            boolean matches(java.lang.String, java.lang.CharSequence)
        </function-signature>
    </function>
</taglib>
```

Then in your jsp

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.acme.com.au" prefix="custom"%>
custom:matches('aaa.+', someVar) }
```

This will work exactly the same as [Pattern.match](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matches%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Comment: Clever solution! But would it be possible to return the match result. I tried something with the java.util.regex.Matcher class but I don't know to make it work with that tld-syntax...

Answer (score 5):

You can use JSTL functions like so -

```
<c:when test="${fn:startsWith(myVar, 'prefix')}">
```

Take a look: http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/tld-summary.html

Comment: This doesn't answer op's (and my) question: _"Does anyone know if there is a way to have the string interpreted as a regex instead?"_

Answer (score 1):

for using Pattern.matches inside a jsp page in my case it was enough to call 
java.util.regex.Pattern.matches(regexString,stringToCompare) because you can't import package in jsp

Comment: Noted should be that this wasn't possible until EL 2.2 was released and the question was asked more than one year before that.

Comment: @BalusC you are perfectly right, i just shared for everyone are searching now :)